# How can I format my JSON in this way?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to output JSON in this format:

```
[{"name":"venue 1"}, {"name":"venue 2"}, {"name":"venue 3"}]
```

But it's currently coming out like this:

```
{"name":"venue 1"}{"name":"venue 2"}{"name":"venue 3"}
```

Here is my code:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM venues";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {

    $arr = array(
    'name'=> $row['name']
    );

    print json_encode($arr);
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: Stop outputting the data inside the while loop; build __all__ of the venues into an array in the loop, then json encode __after__ finishing the loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `$arr[]` intead of `$arr`

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
 $arr[] = array('name'=> $row['name'] );
}   
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$arr[] = array(
'name'=> $row['name']
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Simply make an array like

$array[]["name"]="value1";
$array[]["name"]="value2";
$array[]["name"]="value3";
echo json_encode($array);

you will get the json data as:
[{"name":"value1"},{"name":"value2"},{"name":"value3"}]
which you wants. You have to make the array using looping statements according to your need.
```